# Confusion between numpy, scipy, matplotlib and pylab

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Numpy, scipy, matplotlib, and pylab are common terms among they who use python for scientific computation.

I just learn a bit about pylab, and I got confused.
Whenever I want to import numpy, I can always do:

```
import numpy as np
```

I just consider, that once I do

```
from pylab import *
```

the numpy will be imported as well (with `np` alias). So basically the second one does more things compared to the first one.

There are few things I want to ask:

1. Is it right that pylab is just a wrapper for numpy, scipy and matplotlib?
2. As np is the numpy alias in pylab, what is the scipy and matplotlib alias in pylab? (as far as I know, plt is alias of matplotlib.pyplot, but I don't know the alias for the matplotlib itself)

Comment: On a generally style note, I would avoid the use of pylab (and * imports) outside of the interactive shell. Pylab is a bit of an odd appendix to matplotlib anyways.

Comment: @unutbu: thanks for the link, that makes things clear. I think it also means that scipy is an entirely different modules, and thus unrelated to pylab

Comment: @goFrendiAsgard: You can inspect exactly what pylab imports by looking in `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pylab.py` (the exact path is a little different for Windows or OSX; ask if you need help finding it.)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I look for. I think I will use the more "pythonic" way since pylab is just a wrapper for they who are use to matlab.

Comment: [The mentioned FAQ has a new link.](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related)

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab

Answer (score 136, accepted):

1. No, `pylab` is part of `matplotlib` (in `matplotlib.pylab`) and tries to give you a MatLab like environment. `matplotlib` has a number of dependencies, among them `numpy` which it imports under the common alias `np`. `scipy` is not a dependency of `matplotlib`.
2. If you run `ipython --pylab` an automatic import will put all symbols from `matplotlib.pylab` into global scope. Like you wrote `numpy` gets imported under the `np` alias. Symbols from `matplotlib` are available under the `mpl` alias.

Comment: @Benjamin Bannier What is this then - http://wiki.scipy.org/PyLab? This confuses me.

Comment: @shahensha , it sounds like there are *two* PyLabs; per the link you sent: "...difference between the vision for a **new PyLab** expressed on this page, and the **existing pylab package which is part of matplotlib**"

Comment: [Important update from matplotlib.org:](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#:~:text=pylab%20is%20a%20convenience%20module,discouraged%20because%20of%20namespace%20pollution.)  "`pylab` is a convenience module that bulk imports `matplotlib.pyplot` (for plotting) and `numpy` (for mathematics and working with arrays) in a single namespace. `pylab` is deprecated and its use is strongly discouraged because of namespace pollution. Use `pyplot` instead."

Answer (score 18):

**Scipy and numpy** are scientific projects whose aim is to bring efficient and fast numeric computing to python.

**Matplotlib** is the name of the python plotting library.

**Pyplot** is an interactive api for matplotlib, mostly for use in notebooks like jupyter. You generally use it like this: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

**Pylab** is the same thing as pyplot, but with extra features (its use is currently discouraged).

- **pylab** = **pyplot + numpy**

See more information here: [Matplotlib, Pylab, Pyplot, etc: What's the difference between these and when to use each?](http://queirozf.com/entries/matplotlib-pylab-pyplot-etc-what-s-the-different-between-these)

Comment: [Another example posted directly on matplotlib's site](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related) "Matplotlib, pyplot and pylab: how are they related?
`Matplotlib` is the **whole package**; `matplotlib.pyplot` is a module **in matplotlib**; and `pylab` is a module that gets installed **alongside matplotlib.**"

Comment: Upvoted. Here's [a more legitimate quote about pylab being discouraged](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#:~:text=pylab%20is%20a%20convenience%20module,discouraged%20because%20of%20namespace%20pollution.):  "`pylab` is a convenience module that bulk imports `matplotlib.pyplot` (for plotting) and `numpy` (for mathematics and working with arrays) in a single namespace. `pylab` is deprecated and its use is strongly discouraged because of namespace pollution. Use `pyplot` instead."

Answer (score 4):

Since some people (like me) may still be confused about usage of pylab since examples using `pylab` are out there on the internet, here is a quote from the official matplotlib FAQ:

> pylab is a convenience module that bulk imports matplotlib.pyplot (for plotting) and numpy (for mathematics and working with arrays) in a single name space. Although many examples use pylab, it is no longer recommended.

So, TL;DR; is do not use pylab, period. Use `pyplot` and import `numpy` separately as needed.

[Here is the link](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related) for further reading and other useful examples.

Comment: Recently opened pylab, quickly lept back in terror at what I saw. How was this ever accepted as normal?

Comment: Yes, who knows.